# html ,adding an audio but only a part of it

Tags: html, css, web

I want to add audio on my website but I don't want it to play all of it, just a part of it. And I want it to be played as an "opening voice" so it should play one time. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can specify start and end time separated by a comma like this
`audio.mp3#t={start},{end}`
and set `loop` to `false` to play only once

```
<audio preload="auto" src="audio.mp3#t=150,300" loop="false">
</audio>
```